# Problem creating vector of Pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am trying to create a data structure called Disjoint Set. Looking at theory what i thought of is something like this :

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,std::set<int>>> DisjointSet;
for(auto i=0;i<10;++i) DisjointSet.push_back( std::make_pair(i,std::set<int>().insert(i)));
```

but this code gives which is beyond my understanding , so this is good design to make Disjoint Set. Also how do i get rid of these errors?

Comment: What errors might you be speaking about?

Comment: You need to edit your post to include the error message! But meanwhile I see that you have `>>>`, which you should expand to `> > >` so it doesn't get confused with the right-shift operator `>>`. (In C++0x this is no longer necessary, but you don't say that you are using C++0x.)

Comment: I don't think set::insert returns a set

Comment: @TonyK He uses C++0x (which is obvious from the `auto`) which fixes this ambiguity.

Comment: @pmr: I was thinking about that, but I think `auto` in this case also works in some implementations of C++03 (the type of `int` is used as the default by some compilers, and `auto` simply declares a regular variable). Could definitely be wrong though, I don't have a machine to test this on.

Comment: @Ken By `some implementations` do you mean `non-conforming implementations`? Even when `auto` is used in the original sense of the C standard, that is invalid.

Comment: @pmr: Yes, I was actually referring to non-conforming implementations, as using `int` as a default is *not* valid C++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set::insert` doesn't return the set itself. You need to create the set beforehand, `insert` and then use it in `make_pair`. This does the trick with nearly no overhead for the copy using `move`:

```
std::vector< std::pair<int,std::set<int> > > DisjointSet;
for(auto i=0;i<10;++i) {
  std::set<int> tmp; tmp.insert(i);
  DisjointSet.push_back( std::make_pair(i,std::move(tmp)));
}
```

Comment: @Hades http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure Making this a C++ data structure proper could be some work. Looks to me as a `vector<set<T>>` would be feasible, too. The first element of the pair would be `*set.begin()`.

Answer (score 1):

Well the following code does what I think you were attempting

```
std::vector< std::pair< int, std::set<int> > > DisjointSet;
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
  std::set<int> tmp;
  tmp.insert(i);
  DisjointSet.push_back( std::make_pair(i,tmp) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::set<int>().insert(i)
```

does not return std::set.

Try to do it in several lines:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
    DisjointSet.push_back( std::make_pair(i,std::set<int>()) );
    DisjointSet.back().insert(i);
}
```

Comment: `set::insert` return a `pair<iterator, bool>`.

Comment: @pmr, you are right. I confused insertion of single value with insertion of element range. Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a call to `insert` which makes no sense (since it doesn't return the set). So

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,std::set<int>>> DisjointSet;
for(auto i=0;i<10;++i)
    DisjointSet.push_back( std::make_pair(i,std::set<int>().insert(i)));
```

Should really be something along the lines of

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,std::set<int>>> DisjointSet;
std::set<int> temp;

for(auto i=0;i<10;++i)
{
    temp.insert(i)
    DisjointSet.push_back( std::make_pair(i,temp) );
    temp.clear();
}
```

A little more verbose, but its correct.